# Pl configure the report as below

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch process and the batch runs 5 to 6 times a day. Now my requirement is to generate a report where it shows all the batch start and stop time. When the batch starts it genetates a value 1 and 0 (zero) when stops like as below:

```
Time  Value
7:00    0
7:15    0
7:30    1
7:45    1
8:00    1
8:15    1
8:30    0
8:45    0
9:00    1
9:15    1
9:30    1
9:45    1
10:00   0
10:15   0
10:30   1
10:45   1
11:00   0
```

Report will be like this:

```
Date ..................

             St Time    Sp Time
BATCH ONE       
BATCH TWO       
BATCH THREE     
BATCH FOUR
```

Comment: and how do you recognize how the zeroes and ones are paired? there's no certain order.

Answer (score 0):

This is funny. You showed the input data, but you didn't showed how *that data* must appear in the output report! This means that *any format* in the report is valid, right?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A start=0, end=0
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   if %%b equ 1 (
      set /A start+=1
      set "BATCH[!start!]=   %%a"
   ) else if !start! gtr !end! (
      set /A end+=1
      for %%e in (!end!) do set "BATCH[%%e]=!BATCH[%%e]!      %%a"
   )
)

echo          St Time    Sp Time
set BATCH
```

Output example:

```
         St Time    Sp Time
BATCH[10]=   10:45
BATCH[1]=   7:30      8:30
BATCH[2]=   7:45      8:45
BATCH[3]=   8:00      10:00
BATCH[4]=   8:15      10:15
BATCH[5]=   9:00      11:00
BATCH[6]=   9:15
BATCH[7]=   9:30
BATCH[8]=   9:45
BATCH[9]=   10:30
```